Shall we create a "weekly-topic" tag for the main site?
I created a "weekly-topic" tag on my post on the main site, but I am not sure if it really makes sense as it is not really a "topic".
Shall I remove it?

Looking around at the other sites that have tried this, I think it doesn't really make sense.  I'd remove it.
